# Why std::generate will work with lambda generator and std::fill will not?

Tags: c++, std, lambda

I have stumbled across this website : http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#lambda where they explain ***lambda functions***. I have tried to use the provided examples, namely :

```
    vector<int> indices( notImportantNumber );
    int count = 0;
    fill(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&](){ return ++count; });
```

and similarly

```
    generate(indices.begin(), indices.end(), [&](){ return ++count; });
```

Although, when I try to use the example with fill I keep on getting this error :

> Error 1   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const
>   `anonymous-namespace'::' to 'long'   c:\program files\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility    2692

Anyone knows why is this happening ? In the declarations of `std::fill()` there is no functor as the last parameter.

Comment: I've sent Mr. Stroustrup an email, so his website may be updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an error on that website. `std::fill` takes a value to fill with, not a callable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I thought but I was not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Because `std::fill` does not expect functor as a last parameter - see [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill)

> Assigns the given value to the elements in the range [first, last).

It only expects a single element that will be assigned to every item in the specified range.

Answer (score 0):

Example using std::remove_if and some more STL functions :

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>


int main()
{
    // using STL you can write code
    // that is more expressive and has less (visible) for loops

    // using a set is more maintainable, but just checking a few values
    // with ==5 && ==7 is faster.
    std::set<int> numbers_to_remove{ 5,7 };

    // initialize a list of odd numbers
    std::vector<int> values(5);

    // last argument to generate is a lambda function
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda
    int odd_number{ 1 };
    std::generate(values.begin(), values.end(), [&] { return odd_number += 2; });

    // remove the items from the vector
    // remove_if will only move the items to delete to the end.
    // so one more call to erase is needed to cleanup the vector.
    auto erase_it = std::remove_if(values.begin(),values.end(), [&](const int value) 
    { 
        return numbers_to_remove.find(value) != numbers_to_remove.end(); 
    });

    // or if you don't want to use a set
    // auto erase_it = std::remove_if(values.begin(), values.end(), [](const int value) { return (value==5) || (value==7)}); // using explicit compares.

    values.erase(erase_it,values.end());

    // loop over all the values using a range based for loop.
    // this is safer then using indices, you can't go out of range.
    // const because you don't want to change the values in the loop
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for
    for (const int value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```